# WiredTiger error (2): file-remove: unlink: No such file or directory

Tags: mongodb, docker

I'm building a mongodb image. For some reason the data directory need to be placed inside the image and a config file need to be provided, so that the image file can be loaded into another server and run directly. So I download Dockerfile/docker-entrypoint.sh here:

> https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/tree/58bdba62b65b1d1e1ea5cbde54c1682f120e0676/3.6

and make some changes to Dockerfile:

```
\# VOLUME /data/db /data/configdb
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
COPY mongo.cnf /mongo.cnf
USER mongodb
COPY Theme.json /tmp/Theme1.json
RUN (nohup mongod -f /mongo.cnf > /dev/null 2>&1 & ) \
  && mongoimport -d SIA -c Theme --file /tmp/Theme1.json \
  && mongod --shutdown
EXPOSE 27017
\# CMD ["mongod"]
CMD ["mongod", "-f", "/mongo.cnf"]
```

The build succeeds, but the container fails to start:

> 2017-12-21T16:32:02.024+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
>
> 2017-12-21T16:32:02.024+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=7512M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
>
> 2017-12-21T16:32:02.031+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (2) [1513873922:31861][1:0x7f88beb53980], connection: /data/db/journal/WiredTigerPreplog.0000000001: file-remove: unlink: No such file or directory
>
> 2017-12-21T16:32:02.033+0000 E -        [initandlisten] Assertion: 28595:2: No such file or directory src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 409
>
> 2017-12-21T16:32:02.033+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: Location28595: 2: No such file or directory, terminating
>
> 2017-12-21T16:32:02.033+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
>
> 2017-12-21T16:32:02.033+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
>
> 2017-12-21T16:32:02.033+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
>
> 2017-12-21T16:32:02.033+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100

If I use the original Dockerfile to build the image, run it in interactive mode, and executing mongod/mongoimport, it's fine. So what's the difference between executing the commands from Dockerfile RUN and executing them in the container?

Answer (score 3):

> WiredTiger error (2), connection: /data/db/journal/WiredTigerPreplog.0000000001: file-remove: unlink: No such file or directory

Some journal files seems to be missing. Make sure they were copied over.

If you'd like to try to run MongoDB without journaling, use: `--nojournal`.

See: [What is the difference between journal and non journal Mongodb database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24775568/55075)

If you believe that all files are present, try repairing your database by:

```
mongod --repair --dbpath /path/to/data/db
```